# TypeError: undefined is not an object (TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jqxhr

Im trying to set response array to an interface I have created (ApiPosts[])
And I'm getting this strange error when in trying to update the posts var to the response array.
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.posts = resText')`

Now the response is an array of JSON objects. And when I `console.log(res)` i get an expected array of objects
The code is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { post } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-likes',
  templateUrl: './my-likes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-likes.component.css']
})

export class MyLikesComponent implements OnInit {

  posts:ApiPosts[];


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    var data = null;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        var res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(res);
        setRes(res);
      }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", my url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-apikey", my key);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

    xhr.send(data);

    function setRes(resText) {
      this.posts = resText;
      console.log(resText);
    }

  }

}

interface ApiPosts {
  _id: string,
 address: string,
 price: number,
 rooms: number,
 sqmt: number,
 _mock: boolean
}
```

this is an example of the responseText im getting:

```
[{
    "_id": "5bc98372f27689550002c99d",
    "address": "979 Parisian Divide Suite 335\nTonistad, TX 33097",
    "price": 1472,
    "rooms": 6,
    "sqmt": 984,
    "_mock": true
}, {
    "_id": "5bc98372f27689550002c9a9",
    "address": "416 Barbara Dale\nLake Velva, GA 83588",
    "price": 2028,
    "rooms": 8,
    "sqmt": 1518,
    "_mock": true
}, {
    "_id": "5bc98372f27689550002c9a3",
    "address": "3109 Amely Stream\nJohnsonmouth, UT 83874",
    "price": 3435,
    "rooms": 11,
    "sqmt": 1891,
    "_mock": true
}]
```

im doing it on angular 6 if it makes any difference

Comment: The `setRes` function is defined within `ngOnInit`, therefore `this` is undefined. You need it as a method of your component. Also, you're not using the Angular way of making HTTP requests (should be through a service, at the very least, and ideally using [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http)).

Answer (score 1):

When using a `function` within a method, `this` references something other than the current class [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context).

- in a browser it's the `window`
- in node it's `global`
- in strict mode it's `undefined` unless called as a method:

  - `window.xxx()`

See this snippet for example one outputs `undefined` the other outputs the `window`:

```js
'use strict'

function abc() { console.log(this) }

abc() // outputs undefined
window.abc() // outputs the window object
```

Now if we remove strict, they both output the window:

```js
function abc() { console.log(this) }

abc() // outputs the window object
window.abc() // outputs the window object
```

What you will need to do is create a reference within the method itself, then use that reference within the function like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

  // Your other stuff here...

  let $this = this;
  function setRes(resText) {
    $this.posts = resText;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks much!,It worked, but If you have a suggestion for an easier method to do the same thing i'll be glad to hear, (Assigning get response to an interface variable)

Comment: The easier way would be to make `setRes` as it's own method instead of a function inside of the method